# Bash seed, how to strip the first word and extension in each filename of a group of files?

Tags: bash, sed

I am testing an application for cataloging and storing conversations in our call center. In particular, I am preparing materials for uploading files to the database.
We have many millions of files.
Example:

- Audio_25-09-2018 00-08-33 (1).mp3
- Info_25-09-2018 00-08-33 (1).txt
- Audio_25-09-2019 00-20-39 (2).mp3
- Info_25-09-2019 00-20-39 (2).txt
- ...
- Audio_25-09-2020 00-20-39 (1546879).mp3

Files are divided into pairs, recording and transcription of the conversation. I only need to copy the ones that have a couple.
Example:

- Audio_25-09-2018 00-08-33 (1).mp3
- Info_25-09-2018 00-08-33 (1).txt
- Audio_25-09-2019 00-20-39 (2).mp3
- Info_25-09-2019 00-20-39 (2).txt

To do this, I want to get two lists and compare them with each other:

1. names of transcription files
2. filenames of audio recordings

ls -1 *.mp3 | sed -e 's/.[^_\d|\W]+\d?//' > list_mp3

I want to receive text:

- _25-09-2018 00-08-33 (1)
- _25-09-2018 00-20-39 (2)
- _25-09-2018 00-20-39 (3)

But I get:

- Audio_25-09-2018 00-08-33 (1).mp3
- Audio_25-09-2018 00-20-39 (2).mp3
- Audio_25-09-2018 00-20-39 (3).mp3

I checked the expression and it will filter exactly what I need.
[link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iE3no4/2/)
Why doesn't it work in conjunction with a sed?

Comment: You are using a PCRE pattern with `sed` that only accepts POSIX patterns. Use `perl` with your regex. `perl -pe 's/.[^_\d\W]+\d?//' > list_mp3`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your version with pearl, but nothing happened. The console simply didn't respond.
Сan you help me convert this request to POSIX?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/^[^_]+|\.[^.]*$//g'` or `sed 's/^[^_]*|\.[^.]*$//g'`

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to do this is in pure bash written as:

```
for file in *; do
  datetime=$file; datetime="${datetime#*_}"; datetime="${datetime%.*}"
  # at this time you can do operations using $datetime and $file
done
```

So you can now do something like this:

```
for file in *; do
  datetime=$file; datetime="${datetime#*_}"; datetime="${datetime%.*}"
  # at this time you can do operations using $datetime and $file
  [ -f "Audio_${datetime}.mp3" ] && [ -f "Info_"${datetime}.txt ] && echo "we have both for ${datetime}"
done
```